# Styling a table using CSS

Tags: css

How would I apply a background color that fits the table? How do I change the color of the contents of each cell? How would I give the table a heading/title?

I have composed the following table below:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script Language="JavaScript">
    rows = 6;
    cols = 6;

    document.write('<div style = "margin: 10px; background-color:grey;"><table border="1"
    cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
       document.write('<tr>')

       for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
       {
           document.write('<td>' + (i+j) + '</td>')
       }
       document.write('</tr>')
    }

    document.write('</table></div>')

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am not well experienced enough to apply my needs to the table I created.

Comment: What's the parent problem you're trying to solve? More than likely the answer is *"Don't use a table"* (you've all but acknowledged this with `CSS` tag)

Comment: If one pastes this into Notepad++ and runs it, one should notice the background color (grey) stretches beyond the table. I need it to conform to the table, dynamically - in addition to my humble requests.

Comment: Why is this post marked down? Twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...this should do it

```
<html>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    rows = 6;
    cols = 6;

    document.write('<div style= "width: auto; margin: 10px;"><table style="background-color:grey;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">');

    document.write('<th colspan="6">This is a table header</th>');
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        document.write('<tr>');

        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            document.write('<td>' + (i + j) + '</td>');
        }
        document.write('</tr>');
    }

    document.write('</table></div>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** added the table heading section for you.